# Coordinates on 3D Rotating Monkey Head Example

Tags: python, kivy, coordinates

I'd like to change this code to add an on_touch_up event that would tell wether the Monkey Head was clicked or not. But I'm having a hard time to figure out how the coordinate systems work. I know that the variable touch returns the coordinates of the mouse click, with the bottom left corner being (0,0). If I check the position of the model (the Monkey Head) it returns (0,0). Could anybody help me out with tips on how to aproach this question? Thanks in advance.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.resources import resource_find
from kivy.graphics.transformation import Matrix
from kivy.graphics.opengl import *
from kivy.graphics import *
from objloader import ObjFile


class Renderer(Widget):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.canvas = RenderContext(compute_normal_mat=True)
    self.canvas.shader.source = resource_find('simple.glsl')
    self.scene = ObjFile(resource_find("monkey.obj"))
    super(Renderer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    with self.canvas:
      self.cb = Callback(self.setup_gl_context)
      PushMatrix()
      self.setup_scene()
      PopMatrix()
      self.cb = Callback(self.reset_gl_context)
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_glsl, 1 / 60.)

def setup_gl_context(self, *args):
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

def reset_gl_context(self, *args):
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

def update_glsl(self, delta):
    asp = self.width / float(self.height)
    proj = Matrix().view_clip(-asp, asp, -1, 1, 1, 100, 1)
    self.canvas['projection_mat'] = proj
    self.canvas['diffuse_light'] = (1.0, 1.0, 0.8)
    self.canvas['ambient_light'] = (0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
    self.rot.angle += delta * 100

def setup_scene(self):
    Color(1, 1, 1, 1)
    PushMatrix()
    Translate(0, 0, -3)
    self.rot = Rotate(1, 0, 1, 0)
    m = list(self.scene.objects.values())[0]
    UpdateNormalMatrix()
    self.mesh = Mesh(
        vertices=m.vertices,
        indices=m.indices,
        fmt=m.vertex_format,
        mode='triangles',
    )
    PopMatrix()

def on_touch_up(self, touch):
  print "touch: ({}, {})".format(touch.pos[0], touch.pos[1])

def _on_keyboard_down(self,  keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
   if keycode[1] == 'right':
       self.update_glsl(1/60.)
   elif keycode[1] == 'left':
       self.rot.angle -= 1/60. * 100

class RendererApp(App):
  def build(self):
    return Renderer()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  RendererApp().run()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Sorry @Prune, since it's an example from the documentation, I thought people would associate. My bad. I have edited the question to show the code in question. And apologies...